# .Net 6 Console/Service using Newtonsoft Json Serialisation

Tags: .net, .net-core, json.net, .net-6.0, masstransit

I have **upgraded** an old .NET Core 3.1 application to .NET 6.0.  However I'm running foul of serialisation issues.  Much like one can force a web app to use the Newtonsoft serialisation, how can I do this for a console app? Get it to use Newtonsoft.Json.

In my ASP.NET MVC app, I can use the following:

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

However what can I do to force a console app to use Newtonsoft.Json serialisation?

```
<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
```

Comment: There's no `netcoreapp6.0`, it's `net6.0`. What serialization problems are you trying to fix? `Get it to use Newtonsoft.Json` Console applications don't use serialization at all, much less a default one.

Comment: Thanks, I've changed it. Both allowed it to run.  It's processing headers via Mass Transit, deserialising as part of it.

Comment: In a console app one can just call Newtonsoft directly: `var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeType>(someString);` so you must be using some libraries or tools that use System.Text.Json underneath.  You will need to configure each one to use a different serializer on a case-by-case basis.  So, might you please [edit] your question to tag it with whatever tool(s) you are using and also add some basic information on how you are invoking them -- i.e. a [mcve]?  In comments you mention [tag:masstransit] so is that your only issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure MassTransit to use Newtonsoft for JSON by adding the `MassTransit.Newtonsoft` package and then specifying:

```cs
x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
{
    cfg.UseNewtonsoftJsonSerializer();

    // ...
});
```